# UML Modelling Qustion

Tags: uml, use-case

I am in the process of developing some Use Cases for a mobile mapping/gps app. Users will be able to use this app similar to google maps. I was wondering if anyone had valuable input into some possible use cases.

Here are some I came up with myself:

1) Get Current Location
2) Set Destination Location 
3) Create Fastest Route
4) View Alternative Routes 
5) Traffic Estimation on Routes

If someone could help me elaborate or comment on my direction that would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

My first impulse was to flag your question as "too broad", as you basically ask to help you with your requirements analysis. But I give a few hints.

Your 5 use cases don't look bad. But they appear to be just a first rough sketch of the functionality of your app, that needs to be refined. A good model, be it UML or anything else, must be helpful for its reader to gain some insight. Now these 5 use cases could be named by any child who has seen a navigation device once in her life. To be meaningful, questions like the following should be asked and will probably lead to a more detailed use case analysis:

- How are destination locations selected? If there is more than one place called Jacksonville, how will the user be informed, and how will she select the right one? Does selecting the location consist of more than one step, say country - city - road - block, to assist the user?
- How do map data get into the application?
- What kind of alternative routes are considered and how should they be calculated?
- How will traffic data get into the application?

Try to put yourself into the developer's position. Which questions will she need to have clarified to build the right application?